# Auto-complete does not work for user with argcomplete

Tags: python, bash, autocomplete

The auto-completion feature does not seem to work for me. I created a small test script that reproduces the problem on my setup (Ubuntu 20.04, bash 5.0.17, python 3.8):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# PYTHON_ARGCOMPLETE_OK

import argparse
import argcomplete

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Parser test')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', type=int, default=1346)
    parser.add_argument('--host', default='localhost')
    argcomplete.autocomplete(parser)
    parser.parse_args()
```

I have install argcomplete by running `pip3 install argcomplete` and activated it by running `activate-global-python-argcomplete --user`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Whilst writing this question I found that for python3 I should be using `sudo activate-global-python-argcomplete3` followed by `exec bash` to enable it.